# Read pdf files placed at one server from another server

Tags: java

I have two node on production environment. I have placed pdf files at one server and want to read it from both server. when am calling 'file' method directly pdf get displayed in browser but when i call 'pdfFiles' nothing is displayed in browser.

```
public Resolution file(){
    try {
        final HttpServletRequest request = getContext().getRequest();
        String fileName = (String) request.getParameter("file");

        File file = new File("pdf file directory ex /root/pdffiles/" + fileName);

        getContext().getResponse().setContentType("application/pdf");
        getContext().getResponse().addHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(file);

        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(streamIn);
        int readBytes = 0;
        ServletOutputStream stream = getContext().getResponse().getOutputStream();
        // read from the file; write to the ServletOutputStream
        while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1)
            stream.write(readBytes);

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        LOGGER.logError("reports", exc);
    }
    return null;
}

public Resolution pdfFile() {
    final HttpServletRequest request = getContext().getRequest();
    final HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    try {
        String fileName = (String) request.getParameter("file");
        final String url = "http://" + serverNameNode1 //having pdf files
                + "/test/sm.action?reports&file=" + fileName;

        final PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);

        try {
            client.executeMethod(method);
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
        }

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.logError("pdfReports", "error occured2 " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: when i call method 'pdfFile()' it hit url n call function 'file()'. i don't want the flow to come back on 'pdfFile()' method.

Answer (score 0):

Included below part of code after 'client.executeMethod(method);' in 'pdfFile()' method and it works for me.

```
buf = new BufferedInputStream(method.getResponseBodyAsStream());
            int readBytes = 0;
            stream = getContext().getResponse().getOutputStream();
            // write to the ServletOutputStream
            while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1)
                stream.write(readBytes);
```